# Split a string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

How to split these strings in jquery?

- Mode1
- 2Level

I want to get only the numbers from the above two strings in jquery... The strings may be `Mode11,Mode111,22Level,222Level` etc the characters `Mode` and `Level` wont change...

Comment: You want to split the strings, but only get the numbers? Does that mean we can discard the rest of the string?

Comment: A serious advice: Learn JavaScript. jQuery is "just" a framework (or tool or whatever you want to call it) that makes things easier especially when dealing with DOM. But it does **not at all** make the usage of plain JavaScript obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var num = parseInt(myString.match(/\d+/)[0]);
```

Comment: What's `string`? And why are you passing `myString` as the second argument to a non-existent `match` method? I think what you meant was `myString.match(/\d+/)`...

Comment: Also, the match operation will return an array of matches, not a single number.

Answer (score 1):

var myString="Mode111";
var num =myString.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,"");

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var numbers = "Mode111".match(/\d/g).join("")
var alpha = "Mode111".match(/[a-z]/gi).join("")
```

I think there is an easier way with match collections but I can't find anything to show whether javascript supports them. I will see if I can find it.

Comment: The only assumption that this code is making is that string will always be defined and not an undefined object. But I didn't think that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `String.prototype.match` method:

```
var str = 'Mode1';
var match = str.match(/\d+/);
var number = match && +match[0];
// If `str` contained no numbers then number === null
```

The unary plus operator (+) casts its operand to an actual number (from a string containing numbers).

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'Mode123';
var num = str.match(/\d/g).join('');
```

or

```
var num = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

Comment: The second example would be better with `/\D+/g` as this will match *all* non-digit characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help you

**var number = input_string.replace(/\D/g,'');**